# xymatrix (or else) : create an arrow which points to the content of a cell, ie which follows the content

Tags: arrows, xymatrix

I have a regular `xymatrix` in which an arrow goes from cell 1-1 to cell 2-1.

Now if I decide to move the content of cell 2-1 to cell 2-2, I'd like the arrow to "follow the content", that is go from 1-1 to 2-2 without me having to actually modify the arrow.

My code :

```
\xymatrix{ A \ar[d] & B \\ C & }
```

When I move the content C to cell 2-2, I get this, and the arrow points to the empty cell:

```
\xymatrix{ A \ar[d] & B\\   & C }
```

Any way to make the arrow follow the content?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `tikz-cd` is very simple, just give an alias to the destination node (in my MWE `Z`), putting `|[alias=<alias>]|` before the cell content, and add `to=<alias>` as an option to any arrow to that node.

See Section 2.3 of the [tikz-cd manual](https://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-cd).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
     A \ar[to=Z] & B \\ 
     |[alias=Z]|C & \\
\end{tikzcd}

\begin{tikzcd}
    A \ar[to=Z] & B \\ 
    & |[alias=Z]|C\\
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is pretty nice, and the syntax is real close to this huge xymatrix I already created. So I'll just convert it to tikzcd and have it working in a matter of minutes. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

With `pstricks`, just give a name to the nodes of the `psmatrix`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}% for compilation with pdflatex

\begin{document}

\psset{linewidth = 0.5pt, arrows = ->, arrowinset = 0.12, nodesep = 2pt, colsep = 1.25cm, rowsep =0.9cm}

\begin{psmatrix}
[name = A] A & [name = B] B \\
  & [name = C] C
  %% arrows
  \ncline{A}{C}
  \ncline{C}{B}
\end{psmatrix}
\hspace{1.5cm}
 \begin{psmatrix}
[name = A] A & [name = B] B \\
[name = C] C
  %% arrows
  \ncline{A}{C}
  \ncline{C}{B}
\end{psmatrix}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: For sure, this is pretty much the same solution as tikz and I'll still have to convert. I also want to make different style of arrows, I guess both pstricks and tikz allow that easily.

Comment: I think it's easier to find details on the different parameters in use with `pstricks` (§15, *Arrowheads and such* of `pst-user.pdf`).  Note it has a `pst-arrow` module defining large arrows, multiple arrows within a line, &c.